# Compiling a loadable kernel module(Debian/Ubuntu)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, kernel-module

This question is a follow up of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973146/compiling-an-individual-kernel-module-debian-ubuntu) one. I am trying to compile the ELF loader as an individual LKM and use it as a standalone application(replacing the original module within the base kernel sounds too risky). 
Up to this point I have copied the [source file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/binfmt_elf.c) into a separate directory tree and attempted to compile it using the following **Makefile**:

```
obj-m += binfmt_elf_mod.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The module is generate but the following warnings are given:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/build M=/path/to/source/Resources modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "start_thread" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "arch_randomize_brk" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "find_extend_vma" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "security_bprm_secureexec" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "vdso_enabled" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "arch_align_stack" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "arch_setup_additional_pages" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "randomize_va_space" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "set_personality_64bit" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "elf_core_write_extra_data" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "get_dump_page" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "elf_core_write_extra_phdrs" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "task_cputime" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "elf_core_extra_data_size" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "copy_siginfo_to_user" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "thread_group_cputime" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "elf_core_extra_phdrs" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "arch_vma_name" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "get_gate_vma" [/path/to/source/Resources/binfmt_elf_mod.ko] undefined!
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
```

Currently I am building using the default build script in **/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic** instead of the downloaded sources. How is it possible to solve these dependencies?

Comment: Did you try asking on lkml ?

Comment: I've skimmed through the lists and the discussions held there are centered around bug fixes and patches and not really on how twos: http://www.google.com/custom?domains=lkml.org&q=binfmt_elf.c&sa=Google+Search&sitesearch=lkml.org&client=pub-3128732077138691&forid=1&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&flav=0000&sig=IZwGi0IG8Xeqz31p&cof=GALT%3A%23008000%3BGL%3A1%3BDIV%3A%23336699%3BVLC%3A663399%3BAH%3Acenter%3BBGC%3AFFFFFF%3BLBGC%3Adde8e8%3BALC%3A0000FF%3BLC%3A0000FF%3BT%3A000000%3BGFNT%3A0000FF%3BGIMP%3A0000FF%3BFORID%3A1&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practical terms, you can't. The ELF loader in the Linux kernel links against a number of symbols that aren't made available to kernel modules.

Worse, though, if you build the ELF loader as a module, you won't be able to boot your system! Both the module you're building and the executable that loads it are ELF executables; you can't use them without ELF support already present in the kernel.